# Which order does this execute in? (Promises, javascript)

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, request-promise

So I am working with promises and async/await for the first time. From my understanding async makes a function asynchronous and allows other functions to be executed while it awaits a response from a query etc. We were given the following code as an example and asked to describe in which order it executes:

```
const axios = require("axios");

const contributorCount = (repositories, contributorsList) => {
  let repositoryContributorCount = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < repositories.length; i++) {
    repositoryContributorCount.push({
      name: repositories[i].name,
      numberOfContributors: contributorsList[i].length,
    });
  }
  return repositoryContributorCount;
};

const getRepoContributors = async (repo) => {
  const contributorsReponse = await axios.get(repo.contributors_url);
  return await contributorsReponse.data;
};

const getAllRepos = (repos) => {
  const newRepos = repos.slice(0, 5);
  return Promise.all(newRepos.map(getRepoContributors)).then((contributors) => {
    return contributorCount(newRepos, contributors);
  });
};

function listRepoContributorCounts() {
  axios
    .get("https://api.github.com/orgs/wesabe/repos")
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .then(getAllRepos)
    .then((repositoryContributorCounts) => {
      return repositoryContributorCounts;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error;
    });
}
```

By my understanding, in the 2nd function we're assigning an async function to getRepoContributors and that function waits to get a response from the given url. While it's waiting for the response it allows the rest of the code to execute. But why is there a second await for the return statement? Shouldn't you only need the first since the return statement would only execute after the data is retrieved? Also what would be the exact order these functions execute in? 1-4 or 4-1 etc? Really appreciate all the help, promises are the most confusing thing I've ran into in terms of JS so far but I feel like I have decent basic understanding of it. Async/await is complicating things for me further tho

I was also given a 2nd code excerpt which is pretty similar to above and asked to describe the order of execution again.

```
const axios = require("axios");

const contributorCount = (repositories, contributorsList) => {
  return repositories.map((repository, position) => {
    return {
      name: repository.name,
      numberOfContributors: contributorsList[position].length,
    };
  });
};

const getRepositoryContributors = async (repository) => {
  const contributorsResponse = await axios.get(repository.contributors_url);
  return await contributorsResponse.data;
};

const getRepositories = (repositories, upToIndex) => {
  const repositoriesCopy = repositories.slice(0, upToIndex);
  return Promise.all(repositoriesCopy.map(getRepositoryContributors)).then(
    (contributors) => {
      return contributorCount(repositoriesCopy, contributors);
    }
  );
};

const getOrganizationInfo = async (organizations) => {
  const organizationRepositories = await axios.get(organizations[2].repos_url);
  return organizationRepositories.data;
};

function findOrganizationInfo() {
  axios
    .get("https://api.github.com/organizations")
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .then(getOrganizationInfo)
    .then((repositories) => getRepositories(repositories, 5))
    .then((repositoryContributorCounts) => {
      console.log(repositoryContributorCounts);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: You never call any of the functions. Which one are you calling to start everything going?

Comment: everything is in a `then` or awaited, so just follow the chain of calls.

Comment: _But why is there a second await for the return statement?_ First await gets a `response` object, second await extracts `data` from response

Comment: The only reason why you would use `await contributorsResponse.data` is if `data` is a promise rather than the actual value you want. This seems unlikely, so I think it's a mistake. It doesn't hurt because `await` just returns the value if it's not a promise.

Comment: @Barmar This was all the code given and we were just told to describe the order it'd execute in. I was confused about the calling as well and thought I may be missing something :(

Comment: I guess `listRepoContributorCounts()` is the main function, since all the other functions are called downstream of this.

Comment: @GrafiCode by my understanding retrieving the response object could take some time depending on the external source right but once it's received it should be quick to extract? Maybe this is hard for me to understand since I'm working with minimal sized data while learning and it'd be a bigger issue with larger sizes

Comment: that's correct as @Barmar noted, I confused it with `fetch`

Comment: This code is very confusing, because it's using `.then()` and `await` unnecessarily. `response.data` isn't a promise, so you don't need to process it with `.then()` -- the author also seems to be confusing it with `fetch()`, where you have to call `response.text()` or `response.json()` and they return promises.

Comment: And the last function needs to begin with `return axios`. Otherwise, repositoryContributorCounts` is simply discarded, because nothing can retrieve the return value of the last `.then()`.

Comment: @Barmar I really appreciate all the help! I was also given a 2nd code excerpt which is similar to the first one. They want me to describe the order of execution again and I was wondering if this one made more sense? Once again thank you for all of your help this is extremely confusing

I have gone ahead and edited the main post with the 2nd code sample

Comment: I've written an answer for the first block of code. I'm not sure there's much significantly different in the second.

Comment: @Barmar you are amazing thank you so much!! cleared up all my confusion :) you're right the 2nd code is pretty much the same with just different names I really appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` doesn't make a function asynchronous. It does two things:

1. Wrap the body of the function in a `Promise` and return that promise; this allows callers to use `.then()` or `await` to get the result of the function.
2. Allow the use of `await` inside the function.

The function is actually asynchronous if it calls other asynchronous functions; in this example, `axios.get()` is async.

`await` allows you to call an async function that returns a promise as if your code is sequential. But it only makes the code within the calling function sequential-like; the function actually returns the promise immediately, and other code that doesn't wait for it can proceed. This keeps the application from locking up while the async operation is taking place.

But since all the code in your example uses either `await` or `.then()`, it's mostly sequential within this context.

`listRepoContributorCounts()` calls `axios.get()` and uses `.then()` to wait for its response.

After getting the response, it calls `getAllRepos()` with the array from `response.data`.

`getAllRepos()` calls `newRepos.map(getRepoContributors)`.
Each of the calls to `getRepoContributors()` performs an `axios.get()` call, which is asynchronous, and returns its promise. So these AJAX requests run concurrently.

Then it calls `Promise.all()` on this array of promises, which makes it wait for all of them to complete. The array of values that are returned will be passed to the anonymous function

```
(contributors) => {
  return contributorCount(newRepos, contributors);
}
```

This simply combines the array of repos with the returned contributor data. `contributorCount()` is an ordinary, synchronous function.

This final code:

```
    .then((repositoryContributorCounts) => {
      return repositoryContributorCounts;
    })
```

is totally redundant and unnecessary.